# Unable to publish messages from flink to Kafka : Serilization error

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

Hi I am using the following code to publish messages from flink to Kafka.

```
final Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        props.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
        props.put("client.dns.lookup", "use_all_dns_ips");
        props.put("group.id", "flink-consumer-1");

DataStream<String> enrichedJson = flattenedJson.map(new MapFunction<JsonNode, String>() {

            public String map(JsonNode value) throws Exception {
                Integer customerId = value.get("customerId").intValue();
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
                
                String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map.get(customerId).get("name"));
                JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
                JsonNode obj = ((ObjectNode) value).set("name", jsonNode );
                
                json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map.get(customerId).get("mobileNumber"));
                jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
                obj = ((ObjectNode) value).set("mobileNumber", jsonNode );
                return obj.asText();
            }
            
            
        });

        enrichedJson.print();
        
        FlinkKafkaProducer010 <String> producer = new FlinkKafkaProducer010<String>("ENRICHED_CUSTOMER", new SimpleStringSchema(), props);
        enrichedJson.addSink(producer);
```

I am getting the below mentioned error for serilization

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class [B to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster.executeJobBlocking(MiniCluster.java:625)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:121)
    at flink.KafkaFlink.main(KafkaFlink.java:123)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class [B to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:955)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:912)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer010.invoke(FlinkKafkaProducer010.java:382)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:560)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:535)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:515)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(OperatorChain.java:630)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(OperatorChain.java:583)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:679)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:657)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:560)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:535)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:515)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:679)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:657)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51)
    at flink.KafkaFlink$1.flatMap(KafkaFlink.java:90)
    at flink.KafkaFlink$1.flatMap(KafkaFlink.java:1)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamFlatMap.processElement(StreamFlatMap.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:560)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:535)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:515)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:679)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:657)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:560)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:535)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:515)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:679)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:657)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.emitRecordWithTimestamp(AbstractFetcher.java:398)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka010Fetcher.emitRecord(Kafka010Fetcher.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka09Fetcher.runFetchLoop(Kafka09Fetcher.java:154)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:738)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:87)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:306)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:703)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class java.lang.String ([B and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:29)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:952)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you really shouldn't write and read just to set different fields in your json object. You should create one java object (or map), set all fields, then only writeValueAsString once... Also, don't create a new ObjectMapper in the map function - move it out

Comment: @OneCricketeerCan you please tell me what the problem is with using ObjectMapper in the map function?

Comment: It's very expensive to create a new ObjectMapper for every record. Instead, use a RichMapFunction and create an ObjectMapper once in its `open` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink handles serialization differently than regular Kafka producers. Use ByteArraySerializer

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);
```